# How do i get value from sellected checkbox in wix?

Tags: javascript, velo

i am trying to make my first website via wix, i have made few checkboxes with several choices in them, how can i find which choice is sellected in the specific checkbox?

for example i have checkbox:
Are you:
[] Male
[] Female

how can i find if the user is sellected Male or Female in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes are for multiple choices (e.g. Pizza toppings so you can choose some).

In your case, you probably need single choice, so what you need is [`Radio Buttons`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0Rfa.png).

Now, to your question, how to find what the user've chosen?

Well, `RadioButtons` has `value` property (similar to [normal input `value`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp)).

Let's say your `RadioButtons` component's id is `radioGroup1` (the default id Wix gives you), you can get the value by

```js
const userChosen = $w('#radioGroup1').value;
```

Here you can see how it works: https://moshef9.wixsite.com/radio-buttons-value

(You can see the code by by using devtools and opening the file *c1dmp.js*)